# Swapping Port numbers out of a web app in IIS

Tags: c#, html, .net, web, iis

I have a webpage local to my network called teapp1:8080.  I am trying to figure out on how to change the address of the app to teapp1/countdown instead.  Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: you mean remove te port? ":8080", or any port?? anyway in you can modify site link in right menu of IIS wen select the website

Comment: In a way yes.  It would be nice to have multiple apps on this server instead of navigating to teapp1:8080, teapp1:8081 and so forth navigating to the name of the app it self so doing something like this instead teapp1/countdown  teapp1/checker

Comment: well you need a central application running on the port 80, and when you target the app by endpoint `teapp1/coutdown` make a proxy or redirect to other appy,

Comment: Learn reverse proxy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing and then use it to change URL on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about an IIS server, there are options, either set the ip of the machine with the port in the DNS server, or follow this example:

[image: iis]

Under your site of choice (even empty/a redirect page), click "View Applications" and you'll get the window above, click "New application".
N.b.: virtual paths are the aliases of the url.

EX:

- Host name: theapp.com
- Virtual path: /site
- Full site url:    theapp.com/site